# Screen issues (image shifted to the right) with AMD Radeon HD 6850

Tags: installation, graphics, ati

Since I installed my graphics card - a AMD Radeon HD 6850 - I couldn't get Ubuntu to work. I've just installed Ubuntu again but still no success to run it properly. I've installed using updates and MP3 codecs.

When I start Ubuntu, I see the monitor is slipped right. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Your monitor will have controls to move the screen image left and right - have you tried this?

Comment: install the propietary drivers and set the correct overscan

Comment: Are you using the jockey-gtk to install the graphics drivers? If not then try that and let us know.

Comment: All of your responses don't meet with my problem. I see the monitor slipped right but I'm able to login, only login. After login operation, the screen freezes and nothing is happening.

Comment: @Abhijeet How can I install while I'm on login screen?

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same problem with the very same HD6850. Here's what to do:

1. Boot from LiveCD.
2. Mount your hard drive by clicking it from *Home folder* for example.
3. In a terminal, run:

   ```
   sudo gedit /media/hddUUIDcode/etc/default/grub
   ```

   (where *hddUUIDcode* - unique code of hard drive where Ubuntu installed). Hereby you've opened the *grub* file of the installed Ubuntu.
4. In the *grub* file replace the line:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   with

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash vga=normal noapic"
   ```

   Save the changes.
5. Reinstall grub from a terminal:

   - `sudo fdisk -l` (Find the partition you want)
   - `sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt` (Mount the partition)
   - `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda`

   I’ve used the drive */dev/sda* and partition */dev/sda5* in my example. Notice the exact spelling.
6. Reboot and voila...everything works just fine.